# Prove that set of permutation on $3$ elements is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_6,+)$.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, group-isomorphism

> Prove that set of permutation on $3$ elements is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_6,+ )$ (the group with $+$ on $\Bbb Z_6$).

Hello everyone,

I tried to build a function and show that associativity doesnt work because of the permutation but I don't know how to write the proof, I tried using table or examples.

Can someone help please ?

Thank you

Comment: Every permutation on 3 elements has order 1 or 2 or 3. There are none of order 6.

Comment: Every element of $S_3$ has order $1,2$ or $3$. Given a supposed isomorphism, the permutation mapping to the element $1$ in the cyclic group will lead to contradiction since $1$ has order $6$. Or... use abelian vs. not abelian.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by showing "associativity doesn't work" - the permutations on three elements are functions, and the composition of functions is associative, so your strategy seems unlikely to work. The task is, instead, to show that two groups of the same order ($6$) are not isomorphic - pick some carefully selected property from one group and show that it is not shared by the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $S_3$ of permutations of $3$ elements is not abelian.

For instance, consider the transpositions $\tau=(1\,2)$, $\tau'=(2\,3)$. Then
\begin{align}
&&\tau\tau'&=(1\,2\,3)&\qquad& (\text{denote it }\gamma)\\
&\text{whereas }\qquad\qquad
&\tau'\tau&=(1\,3\,2)=\gamma^{-1}
\end{align}

Comment: does that mean ab=ba ? how do I show that ?

Comment: It means there exist permutations $\sigma,\tau$ in $S_3$ such that $\sigma\tau\ne \tau\sigma$. you can consider a pair of transpositions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that $S_3$ is not cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(\Bbb Z_6, +)$ has an element of order six, whereas $S_3$ does not. Isomorphisms preserve orders of elements.